# Batch File/Script -- How to create a log file when copying documents?

Tags: batch-file, logging, copy, copy-paste

I'm new to batch file scripting. I was wondering if this is possible and can you show me how to do it or provide an example?

Scenario:

- I have a file in drive D ( D:\SAMPLE.DOCX )
- Then I will copy it to flash drive ( F:\ )
- Then I have set a log.txt in ( C:\log.txt )
- Then in log.txt will write

  > "user in Windows" copied SAMPLE.DOCX from D:\  to  F:\  + time + date.

Comment: That all seems very possible to me.  Which part exactly are you stuck with?

Comment: Yes, this is definitely possible. As SO is not a free write-my-code platform, I won't give you the code but recommend you to take a look at this website: https://ss64.com/nt/ These commands are especially important for your task: `ECHO`, `COPY`, `%DATE%`, `%TIME%` and the output redirection `>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
copy /y "D:\SAMPLE.DOCX" "F:\"
(echo("%username%" copied SAMPLE.DOCX from D:\ to F:\ %date% %time%)>>"C:\log.txt"
```

This perfectly meets the requirements of your initial question (though I see no value in this answer). Based on my experience on SO i can bet that this will not be all. (I can guess that the name of the file will not be the same every time, some of the drives will be a flash drive and the script should dynamically to detect it , date and time will need to be in a certain format and so on). So when you edit your question please give all the information, try to do some research by yourself and don't expect somebody to do all of work you need.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that the root of the system drive is normally write protected for most operations. This means that writing to a log file there may instead return an `Access is denied` message.

Comment: @Compo - good point. This will be need to be executed as administrator.